# How to separate domain layer from data-access?

Tags: design-patterns

There is a WPF application and it has it's own business logic. There is a separate library, whose task is to store application settings inside a encrypted XML-file. The business logic of a WPF app is associated with objects and their instances, which can be taken directly from the store-intended library (mentioned above).

The question is how to develop a three-layer application in this case? How to make business layer independent? Does business layer should define it's own domain objects (classes), so a data access layer will transform data-types received from store-intended library into them?

Answer (score -1):

I think, you van use MVVM:

```
    Model = business logic
    View = control with visual elements: lables, buttons etc.
    ViewModel = something that use Model and show it on View.
```

Comment: You do not underdstand the question.